# Android webview working too slow with JQuery

Tags: android, android-webview, android-websettings

I am using KendoUi graphs in my android application, the graphs require a lot of jquery to be loaded. The android webview is taking atleast 6 seconds to draw the graphs. Is there any way i can speed up the loading process.

I have already tried:

```
WebSettings settings = web.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
String data="html document from kendo";
web.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", data,"text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

and i have added:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

in my `manifest` file.

I am **not using** internet in this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, you can ... make a native application... or change  device to quicker one...

Comment: In my case LG Nexus is so smooth but lower android versions like 2.3 and 3.0 the webview is so much slow.